# GNUPlot: How to set maximum number of x-ticks

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I have an automated script that generates a graph every day using GNUPlot. The amount of data used for the graph grows every day, so my x-ticks get cluttered after a while. Can I somehow limit the number of major x-ticks so that I always see 5, no matter how many points are plotted?

**Edit:** My comment wasn't clear enough. This is the way I do it at the moment:
I have a variable var that contains a duration, more exactly the number of seconds in 9 days:

> var = 9*86400

And I use `set xtics <start>, <incr>` to tell GNUPlot to only show a tick for every 9 days of data:

> set xtics "20111101", var

The problem is I have to manually change this every once in a while, since the amount of data grows. Could I somehow tell GNUPlot to limit the number of xticks? Or could I somehow change the variable var to include number of plotted points? (couldn't find out how to do this, either)

Comment: At the moment I'm using: var = 9*86400 / set xtics "20111101", var / But I have to manually change this every once in a while.

Comment: Couldn't your script also generate a suitable value for the tick marks based on the data range?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do. But I don't know how to get the number of plotted points. Also, I thought there might be a way to tell GNUPlot to just "limit the xticks to max. 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.  I am assuming you are feeding the input data to this script, and that the number of lines of data decides how many x ticks you will need.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

t=$(mktemp -t ggplot.XXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -f $t' 0          # Remove temp file at script end
trap 'exit 127' 1 2 3 5 15 # Remove temp file if interrupted, also

cat >$t

# 24*60*60/5
xticks=$(awk 'END { print 17280*NR }' $t)

gnuplot <<EOF
# Generated Gnuplot script
set xlabel "blah blah blah, etc"
set xtics "20111101",$xticks
plot [:] '$t'
EOF
```

(Sorry, my Gnuplot skills are obviously not very good any more.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your comment of your question. Maybe you could edit your question, include the comment in it and elaborate what exactly you are doing.

In general you can modify x-ticks in the following way as stated [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29800043.89):

```
set xtics {axis | border} {{no}mirror}  
               {in | out} {scale {default | <major> {,<minor>}}}  
               {{no}rotate {by <ang>}} {offset <offset> | nooffset}  
               {add}  
               {  autofreq  
                | <incr>  
                | <start>, <incr> {,<end>}  
                | ({"<label>"} <pos> {<level>} {,{"<label>"}...) }  
               { format "formatstring" } { font "name{,<size>}" }  
               { rangelimited }  
               { textcolor <colorspec> }  
     unset xtics  
     show xtics
```

So AFAIK it is not possible to explicitly set the number of x-ticks used. Usually gnuplot does that pretty good on its own.

Maybe `set xtics <inc>` or `set xtics <start>, <inc>, <end>` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Woltan. That's exactly what I'm doing already (please read my edited post). But the more points I plot, the messier the labels get. I need to have max. 5 labels on the x-axis, no matter how many data points I have. Sadly, GNUPlot does nothing to stop labels from overlapping. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not at the time this question was asked, but with `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5`, there is a command `stats` that parses the input file and gives all kinds of statistics, including the number of input points, min/max, etc.

These variables can be used for range.

A drawback is that it can only analyze 2 columns at a time. I did not really test this, but re-running `stats` may re-parse the file.